# autosize height of gridcontrol in list

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I've got a winforms application, using devexpress library. In this application I have an overview form with a list of datagrids (gridview controls of devexpress). The number of rows is dynamic, so is the number of datagrids shown. The grids are programatically added to a panel on the form.

The width of the grids need to scale with the width of the form. I managed to do that by setting the property docking to "top". The height of the grids should scale based on the rows inside. But I can't make this happen.

How can I add a grid to the panel (or form) with width set to 100% and height based to content of the grid?

Comment: Resize controls when you add control to the form and handle Form.Resize event to resize them if resolution change or form size change..

Comment: Yes that could work but how do make the grid grow based on the rows inside?

Comment: First get the panelHightChange% and then grid1.Height = gird1.Height (+/-) (grid.Height * panelHightChange%); in this way you will get the amount of height change you need to do on resize

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Niranjan. Growing a grid in devexpress is more complicated that I expected, I found a solution here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ50814

Comment: That's great.. I will put this comment in answer to help others also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Refer this** - [Calculate the "perfect" size/height of a Grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ50814)

> The height of the grid content can be calculated via the ViewInfo
>   object. Follow approach from the [How to change the Grid's height
>   according to the total height of its rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1811.aspx) example.